# Using symbol '_end' in g++ leads to a segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, linker, clang

Consider the following c++ source code:

```c
int _end[1050];

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1050; i++)
        _end[i] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation line: `g++ main.cpp -o main -O0`

Running this code leads to segmentation fault when using gcc-4.8.4 and clang-3.6.0 under Ubuntu 14.04. The strange behaviour is that the symbol `_end` points at the end of a statically allocated array `_end`, not at its beginning. If we replace `_end` with `end_`, everything works fine.

Moreover, if we ask gcc to output an assembly code by providing -S command-line argument, there will be no significant difference between the version with "_end" and the version with any other array name:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.s -O0 -S
$ g++ main2.cpp -o main2.s -O0 -S
$ diff main.s main2.s
1,2c1,2
<   .file   "main.cpp"
<   .globl  _end
---
>   .file   "main2.cpp"
>   .globl  end_
5,7c5,7
<   .type   _end, @object
<   .size   _end, 4200
< _end:
---
>   .type   end_, @object
>   .size   end_, 4200
> end_:
25c25
<   movl    $0, _end(,%rax,4)
---
>   movl    $0, end_(,%rax,4)
```

But if we use objdump to dump the executables and run diff against them, we will see that in the `_end` version the used address is 4200 = 4 * 1050 bytes further than needed:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -O0
$ g++ main2.cpp -o main2 -O0
$ objdump -d main >main.dump
$ objdump -d main2 > main2.dump
$ diff main.dump main2.dump
2c2
< main:     формат файла elf64-x86-64    // "File format" in Russian
---
> main2:     формат файла elf64-x86-64
123c123
<   4004ff: c7 04 85 c8 20 60 00    movl   $0x0,0x6020c8(,%rax,4)
---
>   4004ff: c7 04 85 60 10 60 00    movl   $0x0,0x601060(,%rax,4)
```

As far as I know, gcc compiler may treat variables starting with underscores as it wants, i. e. this is a bad practise to use such symbols in your code. But my question is: what really happens here? Why `_end` is replaced with an address of the end of an allocated array? Why there is no difference if we use "-S" command-line argument, but there is actually a difference in created binaries? Not that gcc and clang behave identically in this case, that is also strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens that begin with `_` are reserved, and you shouldn't use them. It seems that `_end` is an external symbol defined for programs compiled on Linux, and represents the first address past the end of the uninitialized data segment (also known as the BSS segment).

> *Note: On some systems the names of these symbols are preceded by
>          underscores, thus: _etext, _edata, and _end.*

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/end.3.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! But why "-S" command-line argument shows nothing suspicious while compiling this code?

Comment: @MaximAkhmedov That is probably because `_end` is a pointer as any other pointers, and pointer arithmetic is performed when you assign to your array.

Answer (score 1):

**[C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)** 7.1.3 "Reserved identifiers" says:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Then we must know that:

- file scope is for globals (the others are function and block scope)
- ordinary name space includes variables

So according to C99 you cannot use the identifier `_end`.

**GCC implementation**

Now to see why it actually fails on your implementation, use:

```
g++ -Wl,--verbose main.c
```

to see the linker script used.

On Ubuntu 15.10, it defines the symbol `_end` at the end of the data section:

```
_end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
. = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
```

so it is no wonder that accessing memory way ahead of it may segfault.